# get accordion to fill application from top to bottom like itunes in javafx

Tags: java, javafx-2

I'm trying to make my accordion like the itunes accordion...

```
TitledPane t1 = new TitledPane();
           t1.setText("Library");
           t1.setContent(new Text("Hello"));
           Accordion accordion = new Accordion();
           accordion.getPanes().addAll(t1);
```

Comment: Where does iTunes use "accordian" style control ? Are you talking about the album art widget that hides away ?

Answer (score 0):

If you need accordion to use all area of the screen you can just set it as root:

```
    Accordion accordion = new Accordion();
    accordion.getPanes().addAll(
            new TitledPane("Library", new Text("Hello")),
            new TitledPane("Music", new Text("Music")));

    stage.setScene(new Scene(accordion,300,300));

    stage.show();
```

otherwise, please, elaborate you question. Screenshot from iTunes would help a lot.